# RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF does not work

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a textview and a button programmatically in the existing relative layout. The idea is to put the textview in the left corner of the parentView(relativeLayout) and add then the button to the right of the textView. But in the app it looks like they are on the one place. The button is in front of textView, not on the right. Please, give me some advice.

the code:

```
   TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
   textView.setText("...");
   textView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
   int id = 0;
   textView.setId(id);
   final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
                        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
   params.setMargins(16, 16, 0, 0);
   textView.setLayoutParams(params);
   notificationContentLayout.addView(textView, params);

   Button customerButton = new Button(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
   customerButton.setText("...");
   customerButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00b3ff"));
   customerButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
   id = id + 1;
   customerButton.setId(id);

   final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsForButton =
                        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   paramsForButton.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, textView.getId());
   paramsForButton.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP); // with or without that rule everything is the same

   // paramsForButton.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

   paramsForButton.setMargins(10,0, 16, 0);
   customerButton.setLayoutParams(paramsForButton);
   notificationContentLayout.addView(customerButton, paramsForButton);
```

Comment: You don't need this line `paramsForButton.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);`. It will be placed to the right of the textView

Comment: `notificationContentLayout` is a `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: You can't use `0` as the ID for the `TextView`. Make it at least `1`.

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler, unfortunately, no. Still doesn't work. Yes, it is relativeLayout.

Comment: @MikeM., wow! That's the point. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` rules, `0` means `false`, and only applies to rules that don't refer to sibling `View`s, such as `CENTER_IN_PARENT`. Since you've set your `TextView`'s ID to `0`, the `RIGHT_OF` rule you're adding is being ignored, as `false` doesn't make sense with that.

To remedy this, simply set the `TextView`'s ID to any positive `int` value; e.g., `1`.

Comment: Creating an instance of view in code is not advised, instead you can have a separate layout in xml and then try to inflate that layout into your notificationContentLayout.

Comment: @susheeltickoo First of all, there's nothing inherently wrong with dynamically instantiating `View`s. What do you think inflation is, exactly? Secondly, why are you telling me?